# Change JavaScript code to only expand next row, not all next rows in table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to this and trying to work out how something works that someone previous to me has implemented and I need to alter.

We have a table with say 3 or 4 headers and at present one row below it.
JavaScript is used so that upon clicking on a row, it expand to display the next row.

What I'm trying to do is have another table within one of the rows that only shows after expanding.

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report66 tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#report66 tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report66 tr:first-child").show();
            $("#report66 tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
        });
```

```css
.table.tableSection {
        display: table;
        width: 500%;
    }
    .table.tableSection thead, table.tableSection tbody {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table.tableSection tbody {
        overflow: auto;
        height: 250px;
    }
    .table.tableSection tr {
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .table.tableSection th, table.tableSection td {
        width: 33%;
    }
    .td, th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 5px;
     background-color: #00565c;
     color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='report66'>
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th>Header4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='8'>
    Information
    Information
    <table>
        <th>Test</th>
        <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
    </table>
</table>
```

So with this you can see that upon selecting the first row of data it expands and shows the next row. The table within that row, is collapsed and you have to expand this.

Main question is, how can I change this so that the 2nd table is not collapsed? (I'm not bothered about collapsing it)

There are a lot of different methods of achieving this but every single one I find, doesn't seem to fit what I need.

**EDIT WITH ORIGINAL CODE SNIPPET**

```html
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#report66 tr.information-row').hide();
    $("#report66 tr:not(.information-row)").click(function(){
 $('#report66 tr.information-row').toggle();
  });
});
    </script> 
    <style>
    .new table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100% ;
}
</style>

<?php

 if($replacementpending >= 1)
   {

echo "<h4><center><b>Network | Pending Acceptance</b></center></h4>";

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM  `stock`.`replacements.joblog` WHERE `status` = 'Pending' AND `ownership` = 'Stock' ORDER BY `id` ASC";
   $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
   }
 echo
     "<table border='1'>
        <table id='report66'>
            <tr>
            <th style='background-color:#003033'>DB Ref</th>
            <th style='background-color:#003033'>Ticket Ref</th>
            <th style='background-color:#003033'>Item Requested</th>
            <th style='background-color:#003033'>Customer</th>
            <th style='background-color:#003033'><center><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down'></span></center></th>
        </tr>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo
        "<td>{$row['id']}</td>".
         "<td>{$row['req_ticketref']}</td>".
        "<td>{$row['req_model']}</td>".
        "<td>{$row['req_customer']}</td>".
        "<td style='table-layout: fixed; width: 3%'><center><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down'></span></center></td>";
    }
echo
       "
       <tr class='information-row' style='background-color:#00181a'>
       <td colspan='8' style='background-color:#00181a'>
       ";
    echo " 
    <center><h4><b>Additional information</b></h4>
       <table style='table-layout: fixed; width: 70%'>
       <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>CI Name</th><td>{$row['ciref']}</td><tr>
       <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>Requested By</th><td>{$row['req_name']}</td><tr>
       <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>Ticket Reference</th><td>{$row['req_ticketref']}</td><tr>
       <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>Customer</th><td>{$row['req_customer']}</td><tr>
       <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>Date/Time Logged</th><td>{$row['datetimelogged']}</td><tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <legend></legend>
    <h4><b>Delivery Details</b></h4>
        <table style='table-layout: fixed; width: 70%'>
        <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>End User Company Name</th><td>{$row['endusername']}</td><tr>
        <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>Address Line 1</th><td>{$row['address1']}</td><tr>
        <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>Address Line 2</th><td>{$row['address2']}</td><tr>
        <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>City</th><td>{$row['city']}</td><tr>
        <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>Post Code</th><td>{$row['postcode']}</td><tr>
        <th style='background-color:#003033;text-align:right'>Country</th><td>{$row['country']}</td><tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        </center>
       </td>
       </tr>
       ";

   }
   echo "</table>";
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `$("#report66 tr:not(.odd)").hide();` you actually hide all `tr` elements inside the main table, which do not have the `.odd` class name. Since you have another table inside the main one, this rule applies to the `tr` elements in it.

You can explicitly show all rows in the inner table:

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report66 tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#report66 tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report66 tr:first-child").show();
            $("#report66 tr table tr").show(); // Show all inner table rows
            $("#report66 tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
        });
```

```css
.table.tableSection {
        display: table;
        width: 500%;
    }
    .table.tableSection thead, table.tableSection tbody {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table.tableSection tbody {
        overflow: auto;
        height: 250px;
    }
    .table.tableSection tr {
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .table.tableSection th, table.tableSection td {
        width: 33%;
    }
    .td, th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 5px;
     background-color: #00565c;
     color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='report66'>
    <tr>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th>Header4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='8'>
    Information
    Information
    <table>
        <th>Test</th>
        <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
    </table>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to have multiple visible cells, which toggle the visibility of the information row right after the row they are in, the script can be simplified and you can add a specific class to that row:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#report66 tr.information-row').hide();
  $("#report66 tr:not(.information-row)").click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
    .table.tableSection {
        display: table;
        width: 500%;
    }
    .table.tableSection thead, table.tableSection tbody {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table.tableSection tbody {
        overflow: auto;
        height: 250px;
    }
    .table.tableSection tr {
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .table.tableSection th, table.tableSection td {
        width: 33%;
    }
    .td, th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 5px;
     background-color: #00565c;
     color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table id='report66'>
    <tr>
      <th>Header1</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
      <th>Header4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data1</td>
      <td>Data2</td>
      <td>Data3</td>
      <td>Data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="information-row">
      <td colspan="8">
        Information
        Information
        <table>
          <th>Test</th>
          <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data5</td>
      <td>Data6</td>
      <td>Data7</td>
      <td>Data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="information-row">
      <td colspan="8">
        Information 2
        Information 2
        <table>
          <th>Test</th>
          <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thought this did the trick but spoke too soon unfortunately.
So although it shows the detail fine when there is only one row with information in, if i add another row of data, it begins to only show one set of data.
Try the below and you will see what i mean  
<tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Data5</td>
        <td>Data6</td>
        <td>Data7</td>
        <td>Data8</td>
    <tr>

Comment: Okay that didn't show correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/qdm740fx/

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do all these Data1, Data2... Data8 cells have to be always visible? What should happen, when you click on them?

Comment: Hi Dimitar, the idea is to have a single header (column titles) and then below that there is multiple rows of data. When you click on each row, it displays another row which in turn has another table of data within it.
Your first recommendation worked absolutely perfect, but only when there was one row of data, when there was two, it didn't work.

Comment: An edit has been made. I hope I have understood correctly.

Comment: Hi Dimitar, Thanks thats definitely getting there now!
If i end up having different information row for each row of data, is there a way for it to only show the data relating to the row i clicked on? To help you understand the whole intention behind this is there is a SQL query pulling info that and for each SQL row of data, there will be main data to show (data1,2,3,4) and then further data to show within the information row. Im not too sure if this method will work here, apologies if i should have said this sooner.
I have added my full code snippet to the original prompt

Comment: I updated the snippet to work with different information rows, take a look.

Comment: The problem is have is that im using it with SQL pulled data so each row in the database creates a new Data Row with its own new information row.
So by doing it like it is now, it works but when i click the function, it shows all of the information rows rather than just the single one i clicked on

Comment: Did you use the latest JS snippet I posted?

Comment: Im going to hide in a corner now, thanks for your help, i think that has done the trick!

Comment: Haha, happy to help!